In OpenCL, what's the difference between a "host" and "device" command-queues?
In OpenCL, when creating a command queue, we can set the options to indicate that this will be a "device" command queue; otherwise, it's a "host" queue. The C++ bindings have CommandQueue class and a DeviceCommandQueue, but it seems most of the enqueueXYZ() methods are in CommandQueue.
Coming from CUDA programming, I only know of a single kind of command queue, the "CUDA stream"; and it can be synchronous or asynchronous (which is also an option for  clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties) - but there is no "host stream".
So, what are "device" command queues and "host" or "non-device" command queues in OpenCL? i.e. what should I use each of them for, and how do they interact (if at all)?
Note: Assume OpenCL 3.0 with typical extensions if that's relevant (although it probably shouldn't be)
